# Changing default/working directory Xcode 3.2.6

Tags: c++, xcode

How do I change the default directory in Xcode 3.2.6? I'm working with c++ and want to pull data from a file in the same folder as my .cpp files without using an absolute file path.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have that old version installed so I look to see the terminology it used, but I think if you do a get info on the executable (in Xcode) the first tab in the info window has a place to set the working directory.

Comment: quick and correct answer!  Bring up the inspector on the executable and you'll see a "Set the working directory to:" set of radio buttons.  One of the choices is "Custom Directory". You might (but no guarantees) be able to even use the [$SRCROOT environment variable](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html).